# DRF simplejwt refresh access_token stored in HTTPonly cookies

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, refresh-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

I'm doing a project using React and django, I have used a DRF SimpleJWT for authentication. I have stored a access and refresh token in HTTPOnly cookies all are working fine but I didn't find the way to refresh the token. I can't make it through by reading a documentation. If somebody has done it before please share the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I'm not late.

An easy way, you can use [Dj-Rest-Auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) to handle everything.

Otherwise,
If you want to use function views you can use in your `views.py` and add its URL to `urls.py`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@csrf_protect
def refresh_token_view(request):
    User = get_user_model()
    refresh_token = request.COOKIES.get('refreshtoken')
    if refresh_token is None:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
            'Authentication credentials were not provided.')
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(
            refresh_token, settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, algorithms['HS256'])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
            'expired refresh token, please login again.')

    user = User.objects.filter(id=payload.get('user_id')).first()
    if user is None:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User not found')

    if not user.is_active:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('user is inactive')


    access_token = generate_access_token(user)
    return Response({'access_token': access_token})
```

If you want to use class views add this to your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView, TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenRefreshSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import InvalidToken

class CookieTokenRefreshSerializer(TokenRefreshSerializer):
    refresh = None
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['refresh'] = 
self.context['request'].COOKIES.get('refresh_token')
        if attrs['refresh']:
            return super().validate(attrs)
        else:
            raise InvalidToken('No valid token found in cookie\'refresh_token\'')

class CookieTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get('refresh'):
            cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14 # 14 days
            response.set_cookie('refresh_token',response.data['refresh'],max_age=cookie_max_age, httponly=True )
        del response.data['refresh']
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)

class CookieTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get('refresh'):
            cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14 # 14 days
            response.set_cookie('refresh_token',response.data['refresh'], max_age=cookie_max_age, httponly=True )
        del response.data['refresh']
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
    serializer_class = CookieTokenRefreshSerializer
```

Add the below in `url.py` to use the above views to get and refresh:

```
from .views import CookieTokenRefreshView, CookieTokenObtainPairView # Import the above views
urlpatterns = [
path('auth/token/', CookieTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('auth/token/refresh/', CookieTokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

[source](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/71#issuecomment-762927394)

Comment: In `CookieTokenRefreshView`, why would you set the refresh token again in the response. All you do in this view is refresh the access token, so you need to invalidate the old access token and set cookie for the new one.