# Question about Simple JWT TokenRefreshView in DRF

Tags: cookies, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a question about TokenRefreshView.

In the document([document](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_framework_simplejwt.html?highlight=tokenrefreshview#rest_framework_simplejwt.views.TokenRefreshView)), it explains like this.

`class rest_framework_simplejwt.views.TokenRefreshView(**kwargs)`

> Takes a refresh type JSON web token and returns an access type JSON web token if the refresh token is valid.

And I found how this used by code in stackoverflow. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443505/drf-simplejwt-refresh-access-token-stored-in-httponly-cookies/72234917#72234917))

```
class CookieTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get('refresh'):
            cookie_max_age = 3600 * 24 * 14 # 14 days
            response.set_cookie('refresh_token',response.data['refresh'], max_age=cookie_max_age, httponly=True )
        del response.data['refresh']
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
    serializer_class = CookieTokenRefreshSerializer
```

Now, I want to asks some questions.

1. What is `if response.data.get('refresh)` for?

I guess TokenRefreshView is for returning an 'access' type JSON web token.
Is this a code for the situation when `'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True` ?

2. Can we refresh access token (cookie) automatically when access token expires in Django?

Is it possible to handle cookie(including refresh operation) only from server-side?

What I've tried about Question 1.

- I have set 'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS' in `settings.py`
- When I print `response.data` during refresh operation, 'refresh' didn't exist every situation.