# JWT refresh token is in httponly cookie, How to use DRF simple-jwt to regen the token

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a front and backend app, front is react and backend is python Django (DRF), so my problem is I store the `refresh token` inside an `HttpOnly cookie` and send it in every request, but the DRF endpoint for refresh token (`rest_framework_simplejwt.views.TokenRefreshView`) will read the token itself from `request.data` which is the body of the `Http` request, is there a better way to handle this view other than rewriting a custom view?

Comment: You can override `TokenRefreshView` class & implement you ow `post()` method. Can find example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72234917/14457833).